# Php parsing array in function

Tags: php

I am trying to parse the php script to print contents of config file.

bar.php:

```
<?php

$arr = array("monday", "tuesday");

?>
```

mainscript.php:

```
<?php

function foo(){ # define function
$today = date('Y-m-d'); 
require_once( "bar.php" );
foreach ($arr as $value)
{
$foo = $value.$today ; 

echo $foo ;
}
}

foo(); # function call

?>
```

This is what I get:

```
php mainscript.php

monday2015-03-25tuesday2015-03-25
```

This is what I want:

```
monday2015-03-25
tuesday2015-03-25
```

Comment: echo "this is  $value  number\n" ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if your approach is the best but here it goes:

```
<?php
function foo(){ # define function
$today = date('Y-m-d'); 
 require_once( "bar.php" );
 foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo $value.$today."\n<br>";
 }
}
foo(); # function call
?>
```

Appending a `<br>` or a `\n` after each `echo` call would add a new line.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer. Ot of curiosity, do you know `php`?